# Complex Laravel Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design, polymorphism

I am facing some problems on how to set up my tables/relationships in laravel.

**Description:**
A user can have 3 types (tenant, manager, admin). The admin is the easiest type, it has no extra properties. Tenants and Managers have extra properties pertaining to each type. Furthermore, a tenant has a 1-1 relationship to a unit (assuming for now 1 user account per unit) and a manager has a N-N relationship with the properties (multiple managers can manage 1 property and 1 manager can manage multiple properties).

What I came up with so far:

## Method 1

User has a polymorphic relationship and belongs to both the tenant and manager.
[image: method1.jpg]

How my model relationships would be set up:

`User.php`

```
public function subaccount()
{
    return $this->morphTo('subaccount');
}
```

`Manager.php` and `Tenant.php`

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'subaccount');
}
```

**Pros:**

- No hacky code.

**Cons:**

- Cant set up foreign key constraints, subaccount_id can be null if
  user is an admin
- I feel like users shouldn't belong to tenants/managers, this
  relationship should be the other way

## Method 2

Both tenant and manager would belong to the user
[image: method2.jpg]

How my model relationships would be set up:

`Manager.php` and `Tenant.php` these are fine

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

`User.php` would need something like this

```
public function subaccount()
{
    if ($this->type === 'tenant') {
        $resource = Tenant::class;
    } else if ($this->type === 'manager') {
        $resource = Manager::class;
    }

    return $this->hasOne($resource);
}
```

**Pros:**

- Can set up foreign key constraints, no subaccount_id

**Cons:**

- I feel like that "dynamic" relationship in the user is weird and
  feels hacky.

Would love to get different perspectives on this or thoughts on any other way I can build this.

Comment: What about a model user->tenancy->unit and user->manages->property where tenancy and manages are pivots?

Answer (score 0):

If you think about what makes a User a Tenant, you'll probably find that the only thing is their relationship with a Unit. In isolation, a Tenant is just a User if they have no Unit.

Therefore:

```
class User {
  public function Tenancy() { 
    return $this->hasOne(Tenancy::class);
  }
}
...
class Tenancy {
  public function Unit() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class);
   }
}
```

Similarly, your Manager is only a Manager because he/she manages multiple properties. Therefore, you'll need a many-many relationship between the User and Property, with the details of the relationship on the pivot.